# How to search duplicate users in two files and then print those lines?

Tags: for-loop, awk, grep

I have two files: FILE1 and FILE2:
FILE1:

```
user1        1.1.1.1
user2        2.2.2.2
user3        3.14.14.3
user4        4.4.4.4
user5        198.222.222.222
```

FILE2

```
user1        99.22.54.214
user66       45.22.88.88
user99       44.55.66.66
user4        8.8.8.8
user39       54.54.54.54
user2        2.2.2.2
```

OUTPUT FILE

```
user1        1.1.1.1
user1        99.22.54.214
user2        2.2.2.2
user4        4.4.4.4
user4        8.8.8.8
```

I tried with a for loop but with particular succes..
Can anyone write me a code for this?
Thx!

Comment: does the first column have to be sorted?

Comment: it can be, but it is not neccesery. The first column is generated by other code

Comment: see my answer. but I just noticed you didn't output `user2` twice even though it was a dupe. Was that an omission or on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but I'd think a "sort unique" should give the right answer.

```
$ sort -u file1 file2
user1        1.1.1.1
user1        99.22.54.214
user2        2.2.2.2
user3        3.14.14.3
user39       54.54.54.54
user4        4.4.4.4
user4        8.8.8.8
user5        198.222.222.222
user66       45.22.88.88
user99       44.55.66.66
```

Unless, of course, the output file you provided is the entire output you expect. Since you didn't say anything about eliminating lines from the output, I'll assume you want all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to put the larger file first, in this case it was `file2`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}(a[$1]){if(a[$1]!=$2)print $1,$2 RS $1,a[$1];else print $1,$2}' OFS='\t' file2 file1
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}(a[$1]){if(a[$1]!=$2)print $1,$2 RS $1,a[$1];else print $1,$2}' OFS='\t' file2 file1
user1   1.1.1.1
user1   99.22.54.214
user2   2.2.2.2
user4   4.4.4.4
user4   8.8.8.8
```

Alternatively, you can use this but it requires two calls to `awk` and is thus not as fast in performance:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}(a[$1]){print $1,$2 RS $1,a[$1]}' OFS='\t' file2 file1 | awk '!a[$0]++'
```

Comment: Thx for help./.I will try and then inform you